# How to implement hashing for the following

Tags: java, algorithm, hash, hashtable

I am attempting to write a Java program that uses hashing for the following problem. Given a natural-language text, generate a list of distinct words with the number of occurrences of each word in the text. Insert appropriate counters in the program to compare the empirical efficiency of hashing with the corresponding theoretical results.

I understand the basic principle of hashing and hash tables, but I do not know how to implement it into a computer program. My textbook gives no examples, and my professor never went over any specific examples in my class.

I believe the program should first scan the text from a file, but I have no clue where to go after that.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Here's a HashTable class I wrote in Java.  It might help.  https://github.com/JohnKurlak/HashTable/blob/master/HashTable.java.  Just split your text up at spaces to get words.  If the current word is in the hash table, increase the count.  If the current word isn't in the hash table, set the count to 0 at that slot.

Comment: What is the difference between `java.util.Hashtable` and yours one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to research hashing.  Hashing in general takes a range of values and maps them into some smaller range.  So a simple hash function might be:

```
 public int hash(int value)
 {
   assert value >= 0 && value < 1000;
   return value % 10;
 }
```

So my hash function takes number from the range (0 to 999) and maps them to (0 to 9).  A good hashing function will distribute values evenly into the resulting range.

Your goal will be to map each word to some index into your hash table, which will not be as straight-forward as my example.  You will have to do some research on hashing strings.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Here's what i interpret, what your assignment is about.

You're suppose to simply split a file into words and insert them into a `HashMap<String,Integer>` (or a Map with a Hash Table implementation). You are also supposed to time the insertions, random retrievals and maybe even do membership tests on the map.

You will then repeat the same for different files (of different sizes) and verify if the time taken holds up against the theoretical results.